# How to show discount on homepage in Opencart 3.0.3.6 with Journal 3 theme installed?

Tags: opencart

I have Opencart 3.0.3.6 store with Journal 3 theme installed. Many products have discounted price if customer buy in certain quantity. This discount is visible on the product page when customer click on the product on the home page and load the product page. I want to show quantity discount on the home page like the image.

[Opencart Demo site product](https://prnt.sc/HnJhKd87Y8AW)
[Opencart Home Page Product Grid](https://prnt.sc/EEfVcdH3V7go)

[This is what I am trying to achieve](https://prnt.sc/P33mVSNR62B0) to show discount on home page

I figured out that catalog/view/theme/journal3/template/journal3/product_card.twig file shows content on the homepage or as product grid but I am not sure which controller file it gets it's data from. Can some one please help me to locate the controller file and help with the code?

Answer (score 0):

you have to go to /catalog/controller/journal3/products.php.

First of all, you have to find the function called **parseProducts**. Inside this function, the product array is built. So, you have to add a discount index, so you can show discounts on front-end.

The value of discount index must be a return of a model that search available discounts for that product. So, before the product array and store it in a variable, you must call the function model_catalog_product->getProductDiscounts, passing the product_id as parameter.

After that, you'll have an index for discounts that you can call in twig file catalog/view/theme/journal3/template/journal3/product_card.twig, using this:

```
    {% if product.discounts %}
        <div class="discounts">
            {% for discount in product.discounts %}
                
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
```

This is how the controller looks like:

[This is how the controller looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVqq7.png)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I hired a developer and got it done as it was necessary for my site.